TCPDF Image not showing
   private function generatePDF($pdfData)
    {
      
        $pdf = new \TCPDF();
        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        $pdf->SetAuthor('Your Company');
        $pdf->SetTitle('Invoice');
    
        // Add a page
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $logoURL = base_url('/logo.png'); 
        $html = '
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="5">
            <tr> 
                <td width="50%">
                     <img src="' . $logoURL . '" width="150" />
                </td>
                <td width="50%" align="right">
                   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    
        <h1>Invoice #' . $pdfData['invoice_id'] . '</h1>
        <p>Invoice Date: ' .  $invoiceDate . '<br>
        Due Date: ' . $dueDate . '</p>
    
        <h3>Invoiced To:</h3>
        <p>' . $pdfData['full_name'] . '<br>
        ATTN: ' . $pdfData['phonenum'] . '<br>
        ' . $pdfData['country'] . '</p>
   
    <p style="text-align:right;">PDF Generated on ' . date('l, F jS, Y') . '</p>';
        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
        return $pdf->Output('', 'S'); // 'S' returns the document as a string
    }

Can anyone help me solve this problem? I'm using Codeigniter 4, and the pdf is generated but the image doesn't show that's the problem I need to solve. I tried many ways but could not solve this.
When generating the PDF the image should be displayed at the top of the pdf,

dont even know if it helps but in the html of my pdf's when i add an picture i always do htmlspecialchars($Picture)

maybe use "$logoURL = base_url('/logo.png'); etc ...." in a view to see if the img src is correct?

Please use comments instead of posting uncomplete or "have you tried this before" answers
